# HP DESK JET 4125 not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, printing, hp

I recently Bought and installed an HP DESK JET 4125 all in one printer. I down loaded hplip 3.20.9 and printer worked fine until the next day then it refuses to print though the system says it is printing. The printer is connected to the computer via USB cable.
I have tried following the so called solution on the developers portal but NOTHING there makes my system work properly.

Comment: Care to share what you tried as a "so called solution"? Usually hp printers run by themselves, you don't even have to install anything.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the Developers portal and installed hplip3.20.9.run then followed step by step set up instructions  but to no avail I keep getting communications error and nothing prints

Comment: @Kanehekili How do I send copy of Diagnostic results?

Comment: Select the **edit** link below your question and paste the text. If It is too large, you could send the file to `pastebin` via terminal command (you might have to install it first) and add the link of that file into your question

Comment: You did not answer my question: "Why did you install anything?" The printer drivers for HP are usually provided in every Ubuntu Distro. Usually you just need to connect the printer.

Comment: Because the Printer did not respond when I hooked it up. Kept giving me communication error 5012